# CLLocationManager doesn't start location updates when application did enter background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

In my app I need to perform location updates in background. For this purpose I registered my location tracking object as observer like this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(start)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

and this is the method that starts updating location:

```
- (void)start
{
NSInteger downloadsCount = [[SGDataManager sharedInstance] countOfActiveDownloads];
NSInteger uploadsCount   = [[SGDataManager sharedInstance] countOfActiveUploads];

if (downloadsCount + uploadsCount > 0)
{
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
}
```

However location updates never start. But if I change `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` then the location updates work perfectly in background. So how do I make it work for did enter background notification?

I want to note that location updates background mode is enabled for my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application goes in to background it has finite time to finish tasks. After that time the tasks will be suspended.

Try to put your `UpdateLocation` into a background task, like here:

http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/

This example also uses location updates while going into background.

**EDIT:**

In my opinion it's a `CoreLocation` bug. It could be something like: `startUpdatingLocation` method finishes, the background task finishes, but there is still something happening in some other thread that `CoreLocation` spawned and the app suspends this thread because it goes into background. It's just a guess though.

Either way, here's a workaround: extend your app lifetime in background. Do not end the background task when `startUpdatingLocation` finishes, let it run for a couple of seconds.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier back =  [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask: back];
    back = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

This code will let your app run in background for a couple of minutes. You can create a timer that will suspend it faster if you like

```
NSTimer* killBackgroundTaskTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10 target: self
                               selector: @selector(killBackgroundTask:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    [application endBackgroundTask: back];
    back = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Comment: no, background task is not the case. i already tried it. and it should keep working without it. and it works, but only if i start it half a second earlier

Comment: What are you starting half a second earlier ?

Comment: starting it on wilresignactive instead of didenterbackground

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work. Im investigating it right now.

Comment: It looks like you've found an iOS bug :)

Comment: I don't think so. it is likely that we don't know something simple

Comment: this is exactly what I have already tried. it doesn't work. How it will let me run the background task for a couple of seconds?

Comment: Did you try *not* calling `endBackgroundTask` right after `startUpdatingLocation` ?

Just have *ONE* `endBackgroundTask` in the `expirationHandler`.
This will let the app run for 3 minutes after going into background.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XxMe1pJf

this code works for me on iPhone 6 
iOS 8.1.2

See if it works for you and go from there :)

Comment: for me it started working when I started background task then dispatch_after 2 secs startUpdatingLocation and in didUpdate I kill the backgroundTask. You gave me a clue

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable project **Background Modes** capabilities.

Go to project properties >> Capabilities section.

Select **Background Modes** and click switch to turn ON.

[image]

In background mode check **Location updates** true.

This will enable location updates in background mode.